# Set color to z-values based on the z-values

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a surface that I would like to color. The z-values are taken from a 100x100 matrix that range from -10 to 2, and I want something along the lines of

```
If z is between -10 and -9, color [1 0 0]
If z is between -9 and -8, color [.9 0 0]
....
If z is between -1 and 0, color [.1 0 0]
If z is between 0 and 1, color [0 0 .5]
If z is between 1 and 2, color [0 0 1]
```

Now, I want to use the same exact color map on a different surface plot. Again, these new z-values are taken from a 100x100 matrix, but its values only range from -5 to 1. So, I want

```
If z is between -5 and -4, color [.5 0 0]
If z is between -4 and -3, color [.4 0 0]
....
If z is between -1 and 0, color [.1 0 0]
If z is between 0 and 1, color [0 0 .5]
```

Is there any way to achieve this without manually defining a new color map every time I have a new surface that I want to color?

Comment: Enclose those conditions in a function and call that function when you need to plot a new surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't understand the underlying pattern of your color map (and thus translating it into a for loop that automatically calculates the current color based on the data range being currently processed), I would suggest this:

```
z_1 = randi([-10 2],100);
cmap_1 = cell(size(z_1));
cmap_1(z_1 < -9) = {[1.0 0.0 0.0]};
cmap_1(z_1 >= -9 & z_1 < -8) = {[0.9 0.0 0.0]};
% ...
cmap_1(z_1 >= -1 & z_1 < 0) = {[0.1 0.0 0.0]};
cmap_1(z_1 >= 0 & z_1 < 1) = {[0.0 0.0 0.5]};
cmap_1(z_1 >= 2) = {[0.0 0.0 1.0]};

z_2 = randi([-5 1],100);
cmap_2 = cell(size(z_2));
cmap_2(z_2 < -4) = {[0.5 0.0 0.0]};
cmap_2(z_2 >= -4 & z_2 < -3) = {[0.4 0.0 0.0]};
% ...
cmap_2(z_2 >= -1 & z_2 < 0) = {[0.1 0.0 0.0]};
cmap_2(z_2 >= 0) = {[0.0 0.0 0.5]};
```

To retrieve a value and its respective color:

```
my_z = z_1(2,19);
my_col = cmap_1{2,10};
```